# Finding covariance between profit and quality

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, covariance

The quality $X$ of an item is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1]$ and the profit $Y$ is given by $Y = X^5$. Find the covariance between $X$ and $Y$ .

Can someone interpret this question for me?

Comment: google.translate.com ?

Answer (score 1):

The covariance between any two random variables $X$ and $Y$ measures the linear dependence between them and is defined by
$$
  Cov(X,Y)
= {\bf E}[XY]-{\bf E}[X]{\bf E}[Y].
$$
Thus in your case 
\begin{align}
   Cov(X,Y)
&= Cov(X,X^5) \\
&= {\bf E}[X^6]-{\bf E}[X]{\bf E}[X^5] \\
&= \int_0^1 x^6 dx-\int_0^1 x dx \int_0^1 x^5 dx \\ 
&= \frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \\ 
&= \frac{5}{84}.
\end{align}

So it appears that there is a linear dependence between the quality of this item and the profit it generates, though (perhaps sadly) not a very strong one. Maybe there are other dependencies ...

Comment: But can you interpret the question for the OP?

Comment: Actually the covariance is defined by $$Cov(X,Y) = {\bf E}\left[(X-{\bf E}[X])(Y-{\bf E}[Y])\right]$$ and this happens to be $Cov(X,Y) = {\bf E}[XY]-{\bf E}[X]{\bf E}[Y].$

Comment: @Henry I have seen it defined the way wrote it, and then the other equality deduced. Most authors do use the definition you gave though

Answer (score 0):

The covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is $E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$.

The expectation of $X$ is, by symmetry, $\frac{1}{2}$.

For the expectation of $Y$, we calculate $\int_0^1 x^5\,dx$. This is $\frac{1}{6}$.

We have $XY=X^6$ and $E(X^6)=\int_0^1 x^6\,dx=\frac{1}{7}$.

Now all we need to do is put the pieces together.

**Remark:** If the covariance of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ is not far from $1$ or $-1$, then there is  a strong **linear** relationship between $X$ and $Y$. If the covariance is not far from $1$, then $Y$ grows roughly linearly as $X$ grows. If the covariance  is not far from $-1$, then $Y$ shrinks roughly linearly as $X$ grows. In this case, there is of course a very strong relationship between $X$ and $Y$: if we know $X$, then we know $Y$. However, the relationship is highly non-linear.